# Configuring Apache to serve files from a nas

Tags: apache

Planning to add a Raid1 NAS to our home business development network. We have a web server (MAC1) serving the local network with files from its local hard drive. I want to move those files from its local drive to the NAS and serve web pages which then reside on the NAS. Can Apache2 on MAC1 be configured to do this? An attempt to test this before I have the NAS by serving files from a mounted disk on another computer (MAC2) using a soft link from the MAC1 web root to the files on /Volumes/MAC2/Users/user/www failed with 403 forbidden even though I can access the remote files as a local user on the web server.

Comment: Not a Mac user, but I am sure you can host files off your NAS. As to your 403 error. Apache usually connects as User www-data in Group www-data. You will have to make sure this user or whatever user you have configured can read off the /Volumes/MAC2/Users/user/www

Comment: Thanks apesa, changing the apache user:group from _www:_www to 'userme':staff circumvented the error. Not sure if there's a downside for a local server. NAS arrives tomorrow, hopefully all will go well with permissions on shared files, etc.